# SQL get count(*) before several dates

Tags: sql, presto

It sounds so simple but I can't figure it out. I have 2 tables:

TABLE 1 contains a list of projects with the dates at which they were approved.

| PROJECT | APPROVAL_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| A | 12/06/2019 |
| A | 01/09/2020 |
| A | 05/08/2021 |
| A | 07/12/2021 |
| B | 01/05/2018 |
| B | 06/09/2019 |
| B | 12/23/2020 |

TABLE 2 contains dates when tests were performed on these projects.

| PROJECT | TEST_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| A | 01/06/2019 |
| A | 01/07/2019 |
| A | 02/21/2019 |
| ... | ... |
| A | 06/22/2021 |
| ... | ... |
| B | 01/12/2021 |
| ... | ... |

THIS IS WHAT I NEED: For each project, I want to count the total number of tests prior to each APPROVAL_DATE, so I would have this:

| PROJECT | APPROVAL_DATE | TOTAL_TESTS_BEFORE_APPROVAL_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12/06/2019 | 1264 |
| A | 01/09/2020 | 1568 |
| A | 05/08/2021 | 1826 |
| A | 07/12/2021 | 2209 |
| B | 01/05/2018 | 560 |
| B | 06/09/2019 | 790 |
| B | 12/23/2020 | 1560 |

Answer (score 0):

here is how you can do it using left join :

```
select t1.project, t1.APPROVAL_DATE, count(t2.test_date) TOTAL_TESTS_BEFORE_APPROVAL_DATE
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 
   on t1.project = t2.project
   and t1.APPROVAL_DATE > t2.TEST_DATE
group by t1.project, t1.APPROVAL_DATE
```